# Version control for medications

Tags: c#, algorithm, version-control, versioning

I need some help with an algorithm.

I'm tracking medications taken by a patient. I'll end up with entries like these:

```
1/1/22 DrugA 5mg Started DrugA
1/1/22 DrugB 5mg Started DrugB
1/3/22 DrugA 10mg Increased dosage of DrugA
1/5/22 DrugB 0mg Stopped taking DrugB
```

And from that, I need to be able to produce the following:

```
1/1/22 DrugA 5mg; DrugB 5mg
1/2/22 DrugA 5mg; DrugB 5mg
1/3/22 DrugA 10mg; DrugB 5mg
1/4/22 DrugA 10mg; DrugB 5mg
1/5/22 DrugA 10mg
1/6/22 DrugA 10mg
```

In other words, from entries that describe changes to drug dosage, I need to be able to show exactly what drugs and dosages were taken on any given day.

It's a little like source control versioning in that you track changes but can reproduce the whole for any point in time.

To be clear, I would store this information in a database or something. It would be simpler just to store it in memory.

Can anyone suggest an algorithm that could handle this case? I would need to implement it in C#.

Comment: This is going to attract opinions. Here's mine: Use a state machine. Each event (change in drug regimen) produces a new state object. The state object echoes the drugs in the current state for each day that it's queried. Change to a new state and the next day echoes something different.

Comment: So at the start, `State state = State.New(); state = state.Add(drugA); state = state.Add(drugB);` and that gives you a state object that contains drugs A and B on 1/1/22. On 1/3/22, `state = state.ReplaceDrug(drugBWithHigherDosage);` or something like that. On 1/5/22, `state = state.RemoveDrug(drugB);` .

Comment: Are you tracking what _should_ be taken on each day (which you can do from the state changes, and is what you describe) or what _was_ taken (which is what you ask for)

Comment: @madreflection: That's fine for in memory. But how would you query this in a database, or otherwise store this information?

Comment: @Flydog57: I'm not sure the distinction. If it must be one, let's say what was taken. Does that change anything? But I'm not tracking every day. I need to be able to infer each day's dosage from the changes.

Comment: That's where this is better likened to a bank account register. The current amount in the account is always the result of replaying the entire list of transactions, never some cached amount (this is a common criticism of homework assignments of this kind). So the output you want (second block) should be generated from the change events whenever queried. This applies whether you're iterating through time to report what should have been taken, or iterating through drug adminstration records to say what *was* taken on a given day.

Comment: This is where we (the SO denizens) run up against the problem that we don't know much about the system, not least of which include what technical investments and technical debts you have, so it's difficult to answer these questions without being purely academic about it. All we can do is spark new lines of thought for you to investigate.

Comment: I agree with @madreflection, this seems quite well suited for the Online Transaction Processing pattern. Store the original input data, and calculate what drugs they were taking on a particular day only when you need that information. The data set for one patient will be pretty small, so the calculation can be done pretty easily in-memory by loading all the data for that patient when you need their details

Comment: @madreflection: Sort of like a ledger account, yes. Except that I can have any number of totals. Not sure what you'd want to know about "the system." This is purely an algorithmic question.

Comment: What do you mean by *"any number of totals"*? I don't see anything about totals in the original question.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson: Yes, I can see that. The main issue I see there is that there is an unknown number of totals to calculate. The number of medications has no hard limit. So I'm not sure what that query would look like.

Comment: @madreflection: If you liken it to a ledger, when you sum up all the debits and credits to get the balance, then I would need to do that for each drug. And there could be any number of drugs.

Comment: If you need to know how much of a drug was taken / should be taken up to that point, then you would query the state and aggregate.  It's orthogonal.

Comment: @madreflection: Separate concern? It is the concern. I need to understand how I could organize this data and then produce the data I need from it.

Comment: @madreflection: Yes, I don't see how that's related orthogonally. Without that part, I don't have an answer.

Comment: You'll need to post a lot more details if you want help with that.

Comment: @madreflection: I don't understand what details you want. I can store this anywhere. It's all blue sky. I'm asking about the algorithm.

Comment: My suggestion was to load *all* data for the patient, then process it in memory. That's a pretty straight-forward query, it is not affected by the number of drugs being taken. It sounds more like you're unsure how to implement this as an in-memory algorithm, I suggest we leave the persistence details for later

Comment: I think reflection's suggestion is appropriate too though not required and it could be a little foreign if you're not already familiar with event sourcing. You'd have Start, Increase, Decrease, and Stop events that get stored; the patients medication history is the collection of these events. It doesn't sound like you're totaling anything, just showing the events grouped by date. So why is it more complicated than getting a patient's events, group them by date, and then format the drug and dose info as you've shown?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: In a sense I'm totaling things. I'm totaling all changes to a medication as of a given date. But I'm not sure that is the right approach. I suppose I could group by day with the sum of all previous days.

Comment: @JonathanWood from your example, the quantity in each prescription appears to be an absolute amount. E.g. you start with 5mg of DrugA, the next prescription says it is increased and the amount is 10mg. In the output, that shows as 10mg, not 15mg. You only need the latest prescription of each drug, there's no 'total', no 'sum'

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson: Yes. I'm free to make it an incremental amount. But, you're right: my initial thought was to put the total amount, in which case I'd only need the latest as of a given date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've given us just the plain text input, so I'm going to make up a class to represent the data.

```
public class Prescription
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public long PatientNumber { get; set; }
    public string DrugName { get; set; }
    public decimal DrugAmount { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say you have a list of these records, for one specific patient, and you want to produce the output text. To model that, we need some more classes:

```
public class Administration
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<Dosage> Dosages { get; set; }
}

public class Dosage
{
    public string DrugName { get; set; }
    public decimal DrugAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Your algorithm might look like this:

```
var prescriptions = GetPrescriptions(); // Load the list of prescriptions from the database
var administrations = new List<Administration>();
if (prescriptions.Count == 0)
    return administrations;

var start = prescriptions[0].Date;
var end = prescriptions[prescriptions.Count - 1].Date;

var date = start;
var dosages = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
var index = 0;
while (date <= end)
{
    // Iterate through all the prescriptions that happened on this day, and update the dosage amounts
    while (index < prescription.Count)
    {
        var prescription = prescriptions[index];
        if (prescription.Date != date)
            break;

        if (prescription.DrugAmount == 0)
            dosages.Remove(prescription.DrugName);
        else
            dosages[prescription.DrugName] = prescription.DrugAmount;

        index++;
    }

    administrations.Add(new Administration
    {
        Date = date,
        Dosages = dosages.Select(pair => new Dosage
        {
            DrugName = pair.Key,
            DrugAmount = pair.Value,
        }).ToList(), 
    });

    date += TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
}

return administrations;
```

Comment: Yes. I can do something like this. Additional work is needed when your dosage data starts prior to the start date you are reporting on. But that can be done the same way using blunt force. Guess I was looking for something more clever. But this can work.

Comment: The easiest way to avoid brute-force is to do the calculation daily, and save the results. An alternative is to save the full state less frequently, e.g. once a month, or every time all active prescriptions are finished, and brute force the remainder. However both these approaches run into issues if people enter historic data, or have to correct existing entries. I would say the number of prescriptions per patient will always be low enough that you really don't need to worry about the cost of the brute force approach

Answer (score 0):

For further reference, on a high level view the accepted solution can be seen as the [CQRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs) pattern in combination with the [event sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/event-sourcing) pattern.
There is some C# code examples in the links as well.